# Can't edit textarea in JQuery Terminal

Tags: javascript, jquery-terminal

I am loading raw data from a url into JQuery Terminal...

```
var terminal = $('#term').terminal(function(command, term) {
    term.pause();
    //set url...
    $.get(url, function(result) {
            term.echo(result, {raw:true}).resume();
    });
}
```

If the data contains a textarea, it is impossible to edit the text inside because as soon as I click on the textarea, the focus goes back to the prompt. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this using this code:

```
 term.on('mouseup', '.terminal-output textarea, .terminal-output input', function(e) {
     term.disable();
     return false;
 });
```

jQuery Terminal invoke `focus()` in mouseup, where it detects if there was no selection.

will add this to next version.